# Cat drooling in sleep

Tags: cats, health

I read your question about your cat drooling from a couple years ago and am experiencing EXACTLY the same situation, except my cat is a boy. I was curious to know if your cat is still doing well and healthy. Has she started drooling again during hotter weather? 
I checked my cat's teeth and gums but I don't see any signs of dental disease. He seems to be his normal playful self....if anything, he may be a little more aggressive than usual, but he's always been pretty playful. I would appreciate your input since your cat also started doing this at around a year and a half. That's about how old he is, and it is a lot of drool. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've never used this site before, thought I was sending my question directly to a specific user, bee.catt . If anyone has experienced the same thing, I would love some feedback.

Comment: It sounds like a question for a vet.